# infinite-scroll uses same content after page 2 (using Couchbase as DB)

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, couchbase

I use [infinite-scroll with mansonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html) and couchbase as Database. My Problem is that tt loads the same content after Page 2: Here is the code example:

Page 1:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box">Page 1 Box 1</div>
   <div class="box">Page 1 Box 2</div>
   <div class="box">Page 1 Box 3</div>
</div>
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a href="link_to_page_2">Next/a>
</nav>
```

Page 2:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box">Page 2 Box 4</div>
   <div class="box">Page 2 Box 5</div>
   <div class="box">Page 2 Box 6</div>
</div>
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a href="link_to_page_3">Next/a>
</nav>
```

Page 3:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box">Page 3 Box 7</div>
   <div class="box">Page 3 Box 8</div>
   <div class="box">Page 3 Box 9</div>
</div>
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a href="link_to_page_4">Next/a>
</nav>
```

Javascript:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    columnWidth: 100
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
    });
  });
```

When I load the page it shows

Page 1 Box 1

Page 1 Box 2

Page 1 Box 3

->scroll

Page 2 Box 4

Page 2 Box 5

Page 2 Box 6

->scroll

Page 2 Box 7

Page 2 Box 8

Page 2 Box 9

..

My first idea was, that the next link on page 2 point to page 2 again. But when i disable inifinit-scroll I can easily click von Page 1 to Page 2 to Page 3 and so on, using the next Link.

Im using Couchbase in the background and the next link is something like this ([pagination w couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-querying-pagination.html)):

```
?startkey="Box3-key"&startkey_docid=Box3&skip=1&limit=3
?startkey="Box6-key"&startkey_docid=Box6&skip=1&limit=3
?startkey="Box9-key"&startkey_docid=Box9&skip=1&limit=3
```

I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: I got the point while debugging infinite-scroll. It uses the next link from the first page assuming the link contains something like "page=1" and then just increments the pagenumber. Is there any way not to increment that page number but get the next link from the next page.

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue. I agree with you, it should really take the url for the next page from the loaded one, not the initial one. This limits the way you can have pagination parameter. Mine works with decade, something like `?decade=1980` and is not a consistent increment, but this does not work because infinite-scroll does not know how to increment this. This really needs to be fixed. @felle82, did you find a solution for yours?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out this problem, so I am posting my solution.

The comment that it uses the link from the first page and assumes there's some kind of "page=1" in it is correct. It replaces the "1" with 2 for the second page, and 3 for the third page, and so on.

For additional pages, it will only insert elements into the page that match "itemSelector". So, for example, the "container" div and the nav elements are completely discarded when the pages are loaded by infinite scroll. This is bad news if we're trying to supply the next nav element.

In infinite scroll, there's an option you can set for "path", which expects a function(pageNumber). If this option is not set, when it tries to find the next path, it uses the above logic (replacing the "1" with whatever the current page is). However, if you set this option, you can use this function to generate whatever path you want.

Here's roughly what I did:

Page 1:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box">Page 1 Box 1</div>
   <div class="box">Page 1 Box 2</div>
   <div class="box">Page 1 Box 3</div>
</div>
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a href="link_to_page_2"></a>
</nav>
```

Page 2:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box">Page 2 Box 4</div>
   <div class="box">Page 2 Box 5</div>
   <div class="box">Page 2 Box 6</div>
</div>
<nav class="box">
    <a href="link_to_page_3"></a>
</nav>
```

Page 3:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box">Page 3 Box 7</div>
   <div class="box">Page 3 Box 8</div>
   <div class="box">Page 3 Box 9</div>
</div>
<nav class="box">
    <a href="link_to_page_4"></a>
</nav>
```

Javascript:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    columnWidth: 100
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
  },
  path: function(pageNumber) {
      // try to get path from most recent page
      var query = $('nav.box a:last');
      if (query.length > 0) {
          return query.attr('href');
      } else {
          // if none exist, use path from first page
          return $('#page-nav a:last').attr('href');
      }
  }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
    });
  }
);
```